# Chaining animations in Swift with Spring won't work properly

Tags: swift, animation, promise, ios-animations, spring-swift

I've tried chaining animations with Spring, but sadly the docs are pretty unclear about chaining animations (https://github.com/MengTo/Spring).

I have also seen that some people asked the same question but somehow, their answers won't work for me. ([Spring Meng To chaining animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064296/spring-meng-to-chaining-animations), https://github.com/MengTo/Spring/issues/123)

I have tried using the chain like in the Spring examples :

```
func startAnimationSpringChain()  {
    self.springView.animation = "slideRight"
    self.springView.animateNext {
        self.springView.animation = "fadeOut"
        self.springView.animate()
    }
}
```

Here the first animation works but the second one is a combination of the "fadeOut" and a reversed played "slideRight".

Then I tried using Promises of PromiseKit (https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit):

```
func startAnimationPromise()  {
    firstly {
        self.firstAnimation()
        }.done {
            self.secondAnimation()
    }
}

func firstAnimation () -> Promise<Void>{
    return Promise { seal in
        self.springView.animation = "SlideRight"
        self.springView.animate()
        seal.fulfill(())
    }
}

func secondAnimation() -> Promise<Void>{
    return Promise { seal in
        self.springView.animation = "fadeOut"
        self.springView.animate()
        seal.fulfill(())
    }
}
```

This resulted in only playing the second animation "fadeOut" really fast.

Can someone please explain these three functions:

```
animateNext { ... }
animateTo()
animateToNext { ... }
```

because I find it pretty hard to understand what exactly they do.

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it very much and I'm happy about all kind of advice about my code! :)

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `animateToNext` method for chaining animations. It seems `animateNext` does not wait for end of previous animation. Something like this:

```
self.springView.animation = Spring.AnimationPreset.SlideRight.rawValue
self.springView.animateToNext {
        self.springView.animation = Spring.AnimationPreset.FadeOut.rawValue
        self.springView.animate()
}
```

You also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064296/spring-meng-to-chaining-animations) answer.

However it seems not all animations can work properly when using them in one animation chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)